# What effect does locale have on strtol?

Tags: c, locale, string-parsing, strtol

["The GNU C Library: Parsing of Integers"](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-of-Integers.html) says, about `strtol`:

> In a locale other than the standard "C" locale, this function may recognize additional implementation-dependent syntax.

[Documentation on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) concurs:

> Additional numeric formats may be accepted by the currently installed C locale.

I'm vaguely aware of the GNU extension `scanf("%'d", &intvalue)` for "opting into" parsing integers with the thousands separator; but my impression is that the above quotations are referring to something else, something specifically about `strtol` (not `sscanf`), and something that can't be "opted out" except by setting the locale to `"C"`.

What "additional numeric formats" are possible, and in what locale? Obviously the *theoretical possibilities* are endless, so I'm specifically looking for a locale that exists on some current real-world system, and/or is documented somewhere reputable online.

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but at least decimal separation character is comma in Finland instead of a dot/period; also in Finnish 'w' and 'v' have same rank when sorted.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: Thanks; decimal separator is a fairly well-known locale issue indeed, and I've confirmed that `strtod("3,14", NULL)` has [different behavior](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ux49MGMbRz4a1wYz) when decimal separator is `,` versus `.`. But this question is trickier because it's about `strtol`, which is for integers and so doesn't care about the decimal separator.

Comment: The only way to know is to read the documentation for the function for the implementation you're using. If there's no info, the chances are nothing changes (you only get the standard behaviour).  If there's info, it applies to this version, but not necessarily any other version.

Comment: well, thousands-separator it isn't... possibly other digit systems but I couldn't find any yet :D

Comment: On other languages and frameworks locale can apparently support other numeric systems, such as latin (IV == 4) or hinduic.

Comment: Python 3: `int('๔๒')`. Even with `th_TH.UTF8` could I do anything such.

Comment: 'Tis interesting.  POSIX supports the `'` (single quote) modifier for formatted output ([`fprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) et al), but doesn't mention anything similar for
[`fscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) et al.

Answer (score 1):

glibc [had a bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19242) in connection with the [infamous Turkish locale](https://blog.codinghorror.com/whats-wrong-with-turkey/) that was [fixed just recently](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=f5eee5c72b2ab56f3faf4f46729fe82805efde68). The letter `i` wasn't handled correctly in `strtol` because the uppercase version under the Turkish locale is `İ` (U+0130 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE). Even though this behavior wasn't intended, it still affects millions of real-world systems.

That said, I'm pretty sure that there's no major C library implementation that deliberately allows additional numeric formats. The simple reason is that it would lead to serious interoperability issues.

Comment: Very interesting! This is a good example; although glibc apparently considered it a bug. It affected only `base >= 19` (where `i` represents the digit with value "18"). I hadn't thought of bases-other-than-10. I could definitely see an implementation choosing to do something clever with base=64, base=96, etc.; and maybe that would fall under the weasel-wording I quoted. So you think the weasel-wording applies to weird bases, rather than to weird behaviors *in base 10*?